# How do we prove that two propositions which are given below are equivalent?

Tags: logic

$$(\forall x\in X) p(x)\overset{?}{\equiv} \forall x [x\in X\Rightarrow p(x)]$$

Comment: did you got a question that asking you to prove it $?$ I think It's equivalent by def.

Comment: You have a restricted quantifier as well as an unrestricted quantifier ... so you'd need some principle(s) that relate these two types of quantifiers ... However, what you have here is probably exactly what one would use for any such  principle.  In other words, I would think this would be a basic axiom or definition, rather than something you prove.  Still, if you are being asked to prove this, you need to tell us what principles you were given to prove this from.

Comment: @Manx Right .....

Answer (score 1):

I believe the statements $\forall x \in X(P(x))$ and $\forall x (x \in X \rightarrow P(x))$ are logically equivalent **by definition of a restricted universal quantifier.** In other words, the restriction of the domain of a universal quantifier is the same as taking the universal quantification of a conditional statement. An helpful example is

$$\forall x < 0 (x^2 >0) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (x < 0 \rightarrow x^2 >0)$$
Notice, however, that the restriction of the domain of an existential quantifier is the existential quantification of a conjunction. In other words, $\exists x \in X (P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (x \in X \wedge P(x))$. For example,

$$\exists x > 0 (x^2 = 2) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (x > 0 \wedge x^2 = 2)$$

Again, I believe this is also true by definition of a restricted existential quantifier.